# Could not locate clojure/test/check__init.class, clojure/test/check.clj or clojure/test/check.cljc on classpath

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to Clojure and Lisp as a whole. Following Chapter 14 of the [Getting Clojure](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-clojure/9781680506082/) book, it suggests loading `clojure.test.check.generators` in a way that appeared to me as if it's a native library embedded in `clojure.test`.

Turns out it's not. Trying to `(require '[clojure.test.check.generators])` gives an error:

`Could not locate clojure/test/check__init.class, clojure/test/check.clj or clojure/test/check.cljc on classpath`.

Answer (score 17):

The book doesn't instruct clearly that I needed to properly declare `check` as a project dependency before trying to `require` it.

What I needed to do is to open `project.clj` file and, under `:dependencies` add this: `[org.clojure/test.check "1.1.0"]`. Check the latest version on the [library's repo](https://github.com/clojure/test.check).

I'm documenting here since searching for the error string returned nothing straightforward for me to fix the issue. Although this seems pretty basic, this response should save a few minutes of digging around from other people that are also just starting out.